# Multiple sdp (kurento to wowza)

Tags: wowza, kurento

I am new to wowza and kurento,

I studied kurento and wowza for just a while

So my goal right now to be able to pass my kurento sdp wowza

and luckily it was success using this sdp

This sdp I just manually created it and paste it to my `/wowza/content`

test.sdp

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN 192.168.50.4
s=test
c=IN 192.168.50.4
t=0 0
m=audio 43684 RTP/AVP 0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
m=video 1935 RTP/AVP 101
a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000
```

kurento node js

```
var sdp_rtp_offer = "v=0\n" +
    "o=- 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.50.4\r\n" +
    "s=test2\r\n" +
    "c=IN IP4 192.168.50.4\r\n" +
    "t=0 0\r\n" +
    "m=audio 43684 RTP/AVP 0\r\n" +
    "a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\n" +
    "m=video 1935 RTP/AVP 101\r\n" +
    "a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000\r";
    "a=ssrc:22222\r\n";

rtpEndpoint.setMaxVideoRecvBandwidth(12000);
rtpEndpoint.setMaxVideoSendBandwidth(12000);

rtpEndpoint.processOffer(sdp_rtp_offer, function(error, sdpAnswer){
    console.log('Offer:\n', sdp_rtp_offer);
    console.log('Answer:\n', sdpAnswer);
});
webRtcEndpoint.connect(rtpEndpoint);
```

But now I wanted to create a multiple sdp like

test1.sdp

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN 192.168.50.4
s=test1
c=IN 192.168.50.4
t=0 0
m=audio 43684 RTP/AVP 0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
m=video 1935 RTP/AVP 101
a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000
```

test2.sdp

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN 192.168.50.4
s=test2
c=IN 192.168.50.4
t=0 0
m=audio 43684 RTP/AVP 0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
m=video 1935 RTP/AVP 101
a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000
```

test3.sdp

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN 192.168.50.4
s=test3
c=IN 192.168.50.4
t=0 0
m=audio 43684 RTP/AVP 0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
m=video 1935 RTP/AVP 101
a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000
```

and in my node js I have this

```
var sdp_rtp_offer = "v=0\n" +
    "o=- 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.50.4\r\n" +
    "s=test3\r\n" +
    "c=IN IP4 192.168.50.4\r\n" +
    "t=0 0\r\n" +
    "m=audio 43684 RTP/AVP 0\r\n" +
    "a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\n" +
    "m=video 1935 RTP/AVP 101\r\n" +
    "a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000\r";
    "a=ssrc:22222\r\n";

rtpEndpoint.setMaxVideoRecvBandwidth(12000);
rtpEndpoint.setMaxVideoSendBandwidth(12000);

rtpEndpoint.processOffer(sdp_rtp_offer, function(error, sdpAnswer){
console.log('Offer:\n', sdp_rtp_offer);
console.log('Answer:\n', sdpAnswer);
});
webRtcEndpoint.connect(rtpEndpoint);
```

After I did this instead of filling the test3.sdp it only fill the test1.sdp

So My Question is what is the correct way to connect to a specific sdp from kurento to wowza

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the ports in the SDP files, e.g.

test1.sdp:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN 192.168.50.4
s=test1
c=IN 192.168.50.4
t=0 0
m=audio 6990 RTP/AVP 0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
m=video 6992 RTP/AVP 101
a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000
```

test2.sdp:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN 192.168.50.4
s=test2
c=IN 192.168.50.4
t=0 0
m=audio 6994 RTP/AVP 0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
m=video 6996 RTP/AVP 101
a=rtpmap:101 H264/90000
```

Note that in the wowza the IP address represents the LISTENING IP address, so you could use 0.0.0.0 (to be less secure).  In the kurento client it is the wowza's IP address.  The ports MUST match between the Wowza SDP file and the SDP used in the kurento client code.

Note also that you should space the ports by 2, as above.  The control flow will happen on the `$port+1` port.  I find that keeping them proximate, as shown above, makes sense as well.

I don't recall how the `s` field is used so you should probably change it, but I don't think it really matters.

When connected these will appear as Incoming Streams.  Depending on how your transcoder is set up (if used) you will have to make sure they are not overwriting each other. E.g. if `test1.sdp` and `test2.sdp` both output as `live_channel` then you won't see two outputs.  If they output as `live_channel_${sourcestream_name}` then there will be two outputs.